# Como impedir que meu site seja renderizado em um iframe

Tags: iframe

A ideia é simples, eu tenho um site, como eu impeço que outro site chame o meu através de um `iframe`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Usando *Header*

Browsers mais novos aceitam um cabeçalho HTTP com esta finalidade:

```
X-Frame-Options
```

Eis as opções:

- `deny` - não permitido o framing
- `sameorigin` - não permitido se não for da mesma origem
- `allow-from` - permite apenas da origem indicada
- `allowall` - (não padrão) permite framing de qualquer local.

Exemplo em PHP:

```
<?php header('X-Frame-Options: deny'); ?>
```

### Solução JS

Para outros browsers, a única solução é usar um JS para impedir o conteudo de permanecer "enquadrado":

```
if (parent.frames.length > 0) {
  top.location.replace(document.location);
}
```

Mas se o JS for desabilitado no frame, não há muito o que fazer. De qualquer forma, é sempre o *client* quem controla isso.

Comment: Aqui tem um artigo legal sobre isso http://blog.codinghorror.com/we-done-been-framed/

Answer (score 2):

adicione o seguinte header a sua pagina:

[X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options): DENY

você tambem pode usar o `SAMEORIGIN` ao invés do `DENY`