# Como impedir a página de abrir fora de um iframe?

Tags: javascript, get

Não permite abrir link no iframe

```
if (self != top) { top.location.replace(window.location.href) }
```

Preciso de algo em javascript que seja contrário a isso. Quero que minha URL funcione somente dentro de um iframe

Comment: Relacionado (oposto) : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108087/como-impedir-que-meu-site-seja-renderizado-em-um-iframe

Comment: Ter como fazer tem, mas sempre vai dar pra burlar :\

Comment: Algo assim: `if (self == top) { top.location.replace('http://pagina.que/mostra/o_frame') }`

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente sempre vai existir formas de burlar este tipo de bloqueio principalmente com o uso de javascript contudo para os leigos a validação simples já bastaria.

```
function IsFrame () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o código abaixo para verificar se a janela na qual a página foi carregada é a própria janela do browser e não um iframe:

```
if(window==window.top) {
    // Página não está em iframe, portanto lança um erro.
    throw new Error('Esta página somente pode ser carregada em um iframe!');
}
```